# Possible to get Fan Page Update Information via API?

Tags: facebook

I receive an email once a week with information on my Fan Page (like how many more users than last update have become my fan, how many posts, etc). Is it possible to get this info via the FB API so I can show this data where I want outside FB and outside my email?

Answer (score 0):

One of the way is using fql of facebook :

[Group FQL Table](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Group_member_%28FQL%29)

After you can get the group ids, you can use the group_member tables to get all members from that group:

[Group Member FQL Table](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Group_member_%28FQL%29)

You can even use Graph API if you want but I am not an expert of that